# Change input field style when reaches max length limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, maxlength

I created a contact form that has a text input field and `maxlength` set. I wish that when the characters of the input is greater than `10`, then make input field to display in red.

```
<form action="contact.php">
  Username: <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="10"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This isn't possible because it will not allow text longer than the maxlength in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the selector :invalid in your CSS

```
input:invalid {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
```

This will give all your Input elements a red border, whenever they do not meet the criteria (though as stated in one of the comments the number of characters in your input field can never exceed "maxlength").

Comment: Where I added the class invalid in javaScript?

Comment: Actually TylerH is right and the maxlength Limits the number of characters you can enter, so you will have to go with the solution of Matheus208 and use jQuery (or JavaScript whichever you prefer). I will amend my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$("name[usrname]").change(function(){
  if($(this).val().length > 10){
    $(this).css("color","red");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `maxlength="10"` doesn't allow you to insert more than 10 letters. Anyway you can do like this:

```
    function checkUser(user){
    var number = user.length;
    if(number>10){
    document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "red";
   // <!-- document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;  Disable submit button -->`enter code here`
document.getElementById("maxReached").style.visibility = "visible";
    }else {
document.getElementById("maxReached").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "black";
    }
}
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="">
      Username: <input type="text"`enter code here` name="usrname" id="username" oninput="checkUser(this.value);" maxlength="15">
&nbsp;&nbsp;<label id="maxReached" style="visibility: hidden; color:red">Your title is too long</label><br>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

I put maxlength="15" only to show you.
Hope it's correct for you! You will see it working if you put maxlength over 10.
I added a new line in javascript function that allows the script to disable the submit button if the condition is not satisfied if you need it! ;)
Bye :)

Comment: Super and I would add, in addition to coaching in red text "Your title is too long" and indicate the number of remaining characters , how?

Comment: There are several ways. Here's one:
-Add in the if part of the javascript funcion the following line: `document.getElementById("maxReached").style.visibility = "visible";`

-Add next to the input text form this other line: `&nbsp;&nbsp;<label id="maxReached" style="visibility: hidden; color:red">Your title is too long</label>`

We added an invisible line that is shown when the number of characters exceeds the limit. Of course you have to add in the _else_ f the function a line to let the label get invisible again with `visibility="hidden"`

Comment: @user3831928 if you have problems, i can edit the code in the previous answer.

Comment: I want that you change in the previous answer

Comment: @user3831928 done. Hope it's what you needed! A little reputation is well accepted :)