# Using NgClass to highlight fields that are over character limit

Tags: html, css, forms, typescript, angular2-forms

My goal is to change the background to red when the user input reach the max character while they are typing. I understand that the HTML form will not allow them to input more than maxlength.

This is my HTML form:

```
<form>
  <label>Name:</label>
     <input type="type maxlength="10" [(ngModel)]="name"
            [ngClass]={max: name.length > 10} </input>
  <label>Address: </label>
     <input type="type maxlength="20" [(ngModel)]="name"
            [ngClass]={max: name.length > 20} </input>
  <label>Contact number: </label>
     <input type="type maxlength="11" [(ngModel)]="name"
             [ngClass]={max: name.length > 11} </input>
</form>
```

In CSS:

```
>label{
    font-size: 12px;
}
>input[type='text']{
    font-size: 14px;

    &.max{
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: None of your inputs have closing tags

Comment: Thanks for the catch

Comment: If you have maxlength="10" working then just check when that happens with javascript and add class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018692/change-input-field-style-when-reaches-max-length-limit

Comment: You must remove the maxlength `attribute` if you want to show the CSS class when it has more than X chars. Otherwise, it will never be shown because the inputs with this `attribute` do not allow more chars than the limit specified in maxlength. Also, some notes: You're missing quotes after `type = ...`. Input is a self-closing tag. You should not close it. Shouldn't `ngModel` be different for each input?